# Slow internet on Kubuntu 13.04

Tags: internet

My internet is very slow in Kubuntu. I reinstalled Kubuntu but it didn't help. Facebook, for example, takes a lot of time to load, or doesn't load at all. My husband's laptop, otherwise, is browsing fine, on wireless, while my laptop is slow even on wired connection. I'm on a Dell Inspiron N4050.

Hope somebody can help...

thanks a lot!

Silvia

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that I was able to fix with the following steps:

1. Click on the Networking Interface icon;
2. Click "Manage Connections";
3. Selected the "Wired" tab;
4. Selected "My Connection";
5. Click "Edit""
6. Change Ipv6 to "automatic";
7. Deselected the "ipv4 is required for this connection" <sup>(Which I think was the culprit)</sup>

(If this doesn't help you, you might be using Firefox.. If so try using Chromium. That worked for me.)